# Golang packages and using variables across packages

Tags: logging, go, package

So I'm kinda wondering what the best practice is here.

I have an application with several subpackages, some require access to the logger I have in the main package, because i use a custom logger with colors and timestamps etc.

Is the only way of accomplishing this by injecting it like so? (Assuming Handler is in a subpackage called command)

```
type Handler struct {
    logger logging.Logger
}

func NewHandler(logger logging.Logger) Handler {
    return Handler{
         logger: logger,
    }
} 

handler := command.NewHandler(logger)
```

This issue I have with this is that testing becomes annoying since I have to mock the logger for tests. 
I thought about just returning errors that should be logged and let the main package deal with them, but I'd like to run some function async like so

```
go handler.HandleMessage(msg)
```

So idk how to handle errors from asynchronous functions or if its even possible.

So is there a best practice to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts on this:

1. Injecting the resource (logger) is the best way to do this in my opinion.  Directly referencing a global variable is certainly possible, but makes your code hard to change.
2. If you logging.Logger is a concrete type then you can make it work when nil, so allowing you to skip initialisation in your tests.
3. You absolutely can handle your errors in async calls.

On this last point you can use anonymous functions to add additional error handling at the calling site:

```
go func() {
        err := handler.HandleMessage(msg)
        // err handling / logging here
}()
```

If you can pass errors up meaningfully to the calling site that initiated the call then I prefer to do this every time.  You do need to bear in mind that you are still running in a separate goroutine when you come back from HandleMessage().

Comment: Thank you! The anonymous function is a great idea. Could you elaborate on 2? I cannot pass nil. What does a "concrete type" look like?

Comment: If logging.Logger is an interface, then you need to pass an implementation of it to NewHandler in order to make calls on it.  If on the other hand it's a struct{} with a method Log() on it, then in the (log *Logger) Log (msg string) function you can check whether log == nil, and return if it does.  This means that an empty Logger (e.g. just create Handler{}) is still valid - you don't need to initiate it.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. In my case logging.Logger is an interface from a third party library so I would have to write a wrapper around it